# HTTP 500 Error Displaying MAMP

Tags: http

I am trying to test my website locally using MAMP, however I am receiving a 500 Internal Server Error error whenever I enter localhost into my browser. Any idea why this may be happening? I have not tried anything so far to mitigate the issue as I do not know where to start. Excuse me if the question is slightly vague.

Thanks,
James.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to get an internal error is by editing .htaccess or .conf files. If you've made any edits to those files recently, comment them out or revert to the original versions (MAMP bundles original .conf files in an "originals" folder with the live .conf files, so you can copy and paste those back in if something goes wrong). If that resolves your error, slowly add your changes back in until it breaks again, and you'll know where you went wrong.